# Simple Objective-C property setting error

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, setter

In my .h interface:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *myView;
```

In my .m:

```
- (void)setMyView:(UIView *)aView {
    _myView = aView; //Use of undeclared identifier "_myView"
}
```

Why the error?

Comment: Do you have an `@synthesize` line? If so, show it in your question. Do you also have an explicit `myView` method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing that in addition to your explicit "setter" method, you also wrote your own explicit "getter" method for the `myView` property.

When you provide both of the "setter" and "getter" methods for a property, the compiler does not automatically generate an ivar for you. This makes sense since it is possible your property implementation doesn't make use of an ivar.

In this case you must declare your own ivar. Simply do this in the .m:

```
@implementation MyClass {
    UIView *_myView;
}
```

With that you can reference the `_myView` ivar in your "setter" and "getter" methods.

Another possibility is that the property was declared in a parent class and you are overriding the "setter" method of the property. In this case you have no access to the ivar. You need to do this:

```
- (void)setMyView:(UIView *)aView {
    [super setMyView:aView];

    // do other stuff here
}
```

Comment: No, I do not have a getter. That's why I don't understand the error.

Comment: Did you add an `@synthesize` line? If so, post it in your question.

Comment: No, do I need to synthesize?

Comment: No you don't. I just needed to know if you did or not. OK, to be clear - you have a setter but no getter and you have no `@synthesize` line. What version of Xcode are you using? What is your Base SDK? Are you using the latest LLVM compiler?

Comment: What if the parent defines "myView" in its public interface? How do I set the property in that case?

Comment: If you are overriding the "setter" for a property from a parent class then you call `[super setMyView:aView]`. Your class won't have access to the `_myView` property. Also, there is no need to declare the property again.

Answer (score 0):

add second view as a subview:

```
[self.view addSubview:anotherView];
```

Comment: You are answering the wrong question. This one is about the error about a non-existent variable named `_myView`.

Answer (score -1):

Just declaring a property `myView` in the header file does not create an instance variable called `_myView`. What you need to add is the following above the `@implementation`:

```
@interface ClassName ()
{
    UIView *_myView;
}
```

This is a class extension that allows you to add instance variables and properties without letting other classes know. Then, if you don't already have it, add a synthesize line below the `@implementation`:

```
@synthesize myView = _myView;
```

The synthesize command creates getter and setter methods linked to the _myView instance variable. This also allows you to implement a custom setter without having to implement the getter method.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, with newer version LLVM compiler (with newer versions of Xcode), the ivar is automatically generated for you. There is no need to declare the ivar or call `@synthesize` any more. This used to be required in the past.

Comment: I see. I wasn't aware of this, but the answer could still be a solution to the problem, right? I mean, I'm not an expert by any means, but could one also fix the problem by what I suggested...?

Comment: No, your suggestion would not have have helped for two reasons. 1) An explicit ivar declaration and an explicit call to `@synthesize foo = _foo` are redundant to what you already get implicitly with modern compilers. The explicit ivar would have been the proper fix if and only if the OP had created their own "setter" and "getter". But that wasn't the case. 2) It turned out that the OP was actually overriding the "setter" method of a property from this class's superclass. So there was no need for the `@property` to begin with.

Comment: Thank you! Just wanted to check.